# `indexOf` is throwing "Object type does not match RLMResults" exception

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I'm tracking a crash that happens in production where calling `indexOf` on a `Results` throws `Object type <my object type> does not match RLMResults type <my object type>`. I found [this issue](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/2354) on their github, which was addressed by [this PR](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/pull/2356) back in 2015, meaning I already have that fix. Has anyone experienced it since then, maybe with a different cause?

My circumstances are similar to those of the poster of the issue linked above -- the instance passed to `indexOf` might be unmanaged by realm at that point.

Edit: My code looks something like

```
extension MyObject {
   func refresh() {
      let realm = try! Realm()
      realm.refresh()
      let results = realm.objects(MyObject.self)
         .filter( /* some filtering... */)
         .sorted( /* some sorting... */)

      if let ownIndex = results.index(of: self) {
         /* do something */
      }
   }
}
```

The method is called (from elsewhere) on every object in realm after new objects are added:

```
let realm = try! Realm()
realm.refresh()
try! realm.write {
   // iterate over some data to populate new realm objects from
   for objectData in data {
      let object = MyObject()
      object.populateFields(from: objectData) // Just sets some fields on the object
      realm.add(object, update: true)
   }

   for object in realm.objects(MyObject.self).filter(/* Some filter... */) {
      object.refresh()
   }
}
```

The crashes occur on `index(of:)`.

Comment: Please post some code to show in what context you receive this error.

Comment: Having to update __all__ of your objects in Realm every time you add a new object seems like a bad solution. Are you sure you can't just achieve the same functionality using the built in linking objects? Using those you would get rid of your functions causing this issue.

Comment: (1) I can't really, no. My specific case is that `refresh` updates properties called `isFirstOfDay` and `isLastInGroup` on persisted chat messages. This happens as messages are added or deleted, which could invalidate those properties on any of the existing objects. They're not linked to one another, so don't think that linking applies. The filters (that I left blank in my example) are quite aggressive to ensure no unnecessary updates occur though. (2) Please explain how doing that, if I could, would solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

My best guess would be that after `refresh()` your object could be deleted that means you're trying to get an index of invalid object in your extension.

It's probably a good idea to check `self.isInvalidated` before, otherwise if you have a reproduction case please create an issue at https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues.